# javascript template literal not showing line breaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-strings

I have a template literal running on node8.1.2

```
let gameDayReport = `Next 7th Day: ${nextSeventh}
${gameHours} : ${gameMinutes}
Day: ${gameDay}`
```

In my browser it shows as a single line of text, when as far as I know it should retain the line breaks.
I feel like I'm missing something really basic here.
All of my searching leads me to questions of the opposite nature, removing the line breaks.

Comment: how are you appending it to the html? have you tried inserting `<br/>` tags at all?

Comment: "I feel like I'm missing something really basic here" HTML collapses whitespace characters into a single space.

Comment: <br/> tags indeed work. I've never come across this in this way before. I'm also confused as to why so many people are running into the opposite problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer written yesterday has since been deleted. Like zzzzBov pointed out to me in the comments, HTML collapses whitespace characters into a single space.
I answered this to close the question, if this is wrong please correct me.